# Serial python to arduino

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port, pyserial

I want to send serial data (`'a'`) to my arduino using python.

The receiving code on the arduino is the following:

```
char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
if(inChar=='a'){
    //do stuff
}
```

When sending the charachter 'a' from the arduino serial terminal, it works.
However, when sending from python 2.7 (code see below), the rx led flashes but `to stuff` is not executed (i.e. `inChar=='a'` is false).
I tried everything but I can't solve this problem.

Python code:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)
ser.write('a')
```

**EDIT**: `ser.write(b'a')` doesn't work neither

Comment: similar question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19143360/python-writing-to-and-reading-from-serial-port) see if this helps

Comment: @warl0ck I read the post already but it didn't help

Comment: add 
`ser.flush()` at the end or `ser.close()`
reference from [link](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) to make sure the data is sent

Comment: @black next time provide a *minimal, reproducible example* of your problem, because sometimes the *context* in which certain lines of code appear is important to **reproduce** and *identify*the issue, and this holds also when there is *no context* at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your replies. However, it did not solve my problem.

After trying nearly every imaginable solution, I fix it. Between *opening* the port and *sending/reading*, a delay is required - at least with my raspberry.

So this works:

```
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600) #opening the port
time.sleep(1) #wait 1s
ser.write('a') #write to the port
```

Answer (score 2):

When you see the Rx light blinking but the arduino does not seem to receive data, I would check two things:

1) Make sure that the arduino has plenty of time to set up and start serial communications before sending data from the python host. You could include code that causes the onboard LED to blink with a distinctive pattern *after* the `Serial.begin` statement, and then start the python code after that. (LED details: [how to make the LED blink](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Blink?from=Tutorial.BlinkingLED))

2) Make sure that the communication settings are correct. You may want to explicitly set all of the parameters so that you know what they are and make sure they are the same on both ends of the cable. For example, on the arduino:

```
// set up Serial comm with standard settings
Serial.begin(9600,SERIAL_8N1);
Serial.flush();
```

And then in the python code:

```
bytesize=8
parity='N'
stopbits=1
timeout=3

ser = serial.Serial(port_name, baudrate=9600, bytesize=bytesize, parity=parity, stopbits=stopbits, timeout=timeout)
```

Also, if you can send data from the arduino to the python host, then you know that your communication set up is correct.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. Reviewing my answer 24 hours later, it is not very good :( I do not have a citation for the termination character behaviour, and reviewing my notes for a similar problem I encountered, I was not using python, I was using Java. I will edit my answer.

Comment: fine, I removed my comment as it no longer applies. Were you able to reproduce the issue of the OP?

Answer (score 1):

add

`ser.flush()`

at the end after `ser.write('a')`

or

`ser.close()`

reference from [link](http://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) to make sure the data is sent to the port.

Answer (score -1):

You can see my decision here => https://github.com/thisroot/firebox

```
import firebox as fb

serPort = fb.findDevice('stimulator')
if(serPort):
    data = []
    data.append("<fire,200,5>")
    fb.sendMessage(serPort,data)
```

Comment: As it is, this looks like *spam* and does not appear to answer the question in this thread, nor clearly identify and solve the issue within the question. Please edit your answer to provide more details on how this would solve the OP problem and how he can use it in his specific case.

Comment: i don't have time to write more detailed